# Puppeteer not rendering color, background color when I try to save PDF on disk

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

This is my node.js and HTML template code which creates a PDF from an HTML template. It's not putting in the colors.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto("file:///D:/pdf_export/template/template.html");
    await page.pdf({
        path: 'output.pdf',
        printBackground: true
    });
    await browser.close();
})()
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    </head>

    <body>
        <p style="color: red;">Hello World</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I open the output.pdf, it only shows 'Hello world' in black not in red.

Comment: why are you using #! in the html file path?

Comment: I have updated it. But it still doesn't render color

Comment: Can you check if the URL path matches the one you created for the HTML

Comment: I have post the answer, can you please check that on your end.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Puppeteer is just a library to drive Chrome/Chromium, so if anything goes wrong while using it, our best bet is to open Chromium with `puppeteer.launch({headless:false})` and debug there.

Set your page css in `<style></style>` tag.

You can solve the issue with the following CSS code:

```
html {
  -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
}
p {
  color: #FF0000; 
}
```

Comment: What a solution!! it's working perfectly for me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Except that generating a pdf only works in headless mode. The provided solution works but setting `headless` to `false` is not "our best bet" in this case, just saying.

Comment: I have absolutely no idea why this worked, but it's one of those try-it-and-it-solves-everything answers!

Answer (score 63):

For me none of the solutions I found on stackoverflow worked. I almost "lost hope". But after playing around with all the info I found, all that really mattered was:

1. the `printBackground` option has to be set to TRUE, e.g.:
   `page.pdf({ path: "./my.pdf", printBackground: true });`
2. add to your background or color values `!important`, e.g.:

```
p {
  color: #FF0000 !important; 
}
```

That's it.

P.S. regarding the `-webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;` it was useless in my case. I have currently Puppeteer v5.5.0.

Comment: Thanks man, you saved some hairs from my head with the "printBackground: true"

Comment: Perfect! This a first time I use `puppeteer` and you same me hours of tinkering about why no background is in the generated PDF. Just a note: I tested this with `product: 'firefox'` and it works as expected! ;)

Comment: the "printBackground"-Option is the important part here. Otherwise no "background-color" stuff is printed ad all.. Thank you!

Comment: "printBackground" is needed, but nothing worked without also adding "!important" for me as well.

Comment: "printBackground: true"  worked for me. Thank you!