# Background image not appearing when using `--print-to-pdf` option with headless chrome

Tags: html, css, pdf

I have the following HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>CV</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" media="all" />
</head>

<body>
    <div class="leftcolumn">
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

And the following CSS, which sets any elements with the class `leftcolumn` to have a background image:

```css
.leftcolumn {
    float: left;
    background-color: rgb(41, 52, 72);
    background-image: url(test.png);
    color: white;
    height: inherit;
    width: 35%;
    padding: 20px;
}

@page {
    margin: 0
}
```

The background image appears fine when I open up the HTML file in the Chrome browser. If I right-click on the browser and select print to PDF the rendered PDF also includes the background image.

However, when I try to print out the PDF from the command line using the following command:

`chrome --headless --print-to-pdf=test.pdf test.html`

The PDF is generated but fails to render the background image.

How can I get the background image to appear in the resulting PDF if I use the `--print-to-pdf` option in the `chrome` command from the command line?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Puppeteer not rendering color, background color when I try to save PDF on disk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60736354/puppeteer-not-rendering-color-background-color-when-i-try-to-save-pdf-on-disk)

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Definitely not, that question has nothing to do with what I'm asking here...

Comment: Did you try the answer? The CSS rule: `html {  -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact; }`. Do not discard it out of hand before trying it just because the question seems different. I admit I didn't try it, but it could work. See also: [Can I use it?](https://caniuse.com/?search=-webkit-print-color-adjust)

Comment: It didn't work.

Comment: In [the usage notes on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/print-color-adjust) it says: _"If the output device is a printer, and to save ink, dark or extremely dense background images might be removed."_. I know that a PDF is not a printer, but the browser probably still thinks it is printing. I also don't know what your page looks like? Do you know if headless chrome still abides by the user selected options? They will take priority over anything you may do.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I have pasted a minimal working example which you can reproduce on your own machine. You can copy the code and see for yourself. If you come up with a fleshed out solution then please go ahead and post it as a final answer. Otherwise we don't really need to have a long winded discussion in the comments section. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, sometimes the way to get to a final answer is for several people to gradually get there through comments which edge us collectively towards a solution. It’s disappointing that you have dismissed this teamwork approach in your comments to @KIKOSoftware As I’m afraid I only have ideas not a fully fleshed out solution I’ll not trouble you further….

Comment: @AHaworth My issue with the previous person's comments is that they can easily be answered by replicating the MWE which I have taken pains to create and which attempts to make the question as clear and concise as possible. If you have already tried replicating the MWE and have any questions or comments about that, I'd be more than happy to answer/address them.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the --print-to-pdf option with Chrome's headless mode (--headless), some CSS properties, such as background images, might not be rendered correctly in the resulting PDF. This is because headless Chrome is optimized for generating simplified and printer-friendly PDFs, which may not include certain visual elements like background images.

To ensure that the background image is included in the resulting PDF, you can try a workaround by converting the HTML page to a static image first, and then converting that image to PDF. I've seen other people using an external tool called Puppeteer to achieve this.

Can't say I've used Puppeteer before so I'm sorry for not being able to walk you through but it might give you a direction to head towards if nothing else.
https://blog.risingstack.com/pdf-from-html-node-js-puppeteer/

Comment: I like your idea, however user32882 prefers _a fleshed out solution_, so don't be surprised if you also get a grumpy reaction. 